# Bug with Rigibody2D.constraints in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I create a simple game, where should I throw the knife. The knife must be attached to the board. I do this so:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
    if (other.transform.tag == "Board") {
        rb.gravityScale = 0;
        transform.parent = Parent;
        rb.constraints = 
        RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezePositionY;
}
```

Sometimes, once the object is attached to the board, it is deleted even from the hierarchy.

I tested a lot, and when I do not use RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezePositionY (FreezAll), then everything is working.

Comment: In your script create a OnDestroy function and check "who" is calling to destroy your knife.

Comment: thx, I add in this function OnDestroy() instantiate new knife.

Comment: That wasn't my idea, the key there should be to debug and see why the knife is being destroyed.

Are you are the knife is deleted  or is it inside the parent?

Comment: Knife is deleted, and from you I learned about function OnDestroy. But why is deleting I could not find. I thought that if the old one is deleted, instead of it create a new one with its parameters. And this work perfect:)

Comment: Have you tried debugging the function?? In the stack you can check from where is called Destroy.

Comment: about how you can find out where the destroy is called from, I did not know

Comment: In your OnDestroy put a Break Point and in the call stack you can check it out